# How can I check if an object in an S3 bucket is public or not in boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying  to check if all the objects in a specified bucket are public or not, using the boto3 module in python. I have tried using the `client.get_object()` and `client.list_objects()` methods, but I am unable to figure out what exactly I should search for as I am new to boto3 and AWS in general.

Also, since my organization prefers using `client` over `resource`, so I'm preferably looking for a way to do it using `client`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to test if an object is public or not is to make an anonymous request to that object URL.

```py
import boto3
import botocore
import requests

bucket_name = 'example-bucket'
object_key = 'example-key'

config = botocore.client.Config(signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED)
object_url = boto3.client('s3', config=config).generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': object_key})
resp = requests.get(object_url)
if resp.status_code == 200:
    print('The object is public.')
else:
    print('Nope! The object is private or inaccessible.')
```

Note: You can use `requests.head` instead of `requests.get` to save some data transfer.

Comment: This seems to work, but just out of curiosity- is there no key in the response of ANY method that I can use? Seems kind of odd to me that boto3 does not provide support for this, as it is quite easily available on the console.

Comment: @SarthakSaxena That is correct, but since boto3 internally depends on botocore, you don't need to install an extra dependency so this shouldn't be an issue. If you only need to use it to check the objects in this specific bucket, you can even copy and paste the generated URL and construct the string yourself.

Answer (score 1):

may be a combination of these to tell the full story for each object

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'my-bucket'
key = 'my-key'
client.get_object_acl(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
client.get_bucket_acl(Bucket=bucket)
client.get_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket)
```

Answer (score 1):

This function should do the trick. It gets the ACL and then loops through the `Grants` looking for `AllUsers` with `READ` or `FULL_CONTROL` permissions.

```
import boto3

def is_public(key, bucket):
    """Returns true if key has public access.

    Args:
        key (str): key to check
        bucket (str, optional): Bucket name.

    Returns:
        (bool)

    Public object ACL example:
    {
        ...
        "Grants": [
            {
                "Grantee": {
                    "Type": "Group",
                    "URI": "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers",
                },
                "Permission": "READ",
            },
            {
                "Grantee": {
                    "ID": "somecrypticidstring",
                    "Type": "CanonicalUser",
                },
                "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL",
            },
        ],
    }

    Private object ACL example:
    {
        ...
        "Grants": [
            {
                "Grantee": {
                    "ID": "somecrypticidstring",
                    "Type": "CanonicalUser",
                },
                "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL",
            }
        ],
    }
    """
    client = boto3.client(
        "s3",
        aws_access_key_id=YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    )
    d = client.get_object_acl(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

    try:
        for grant in d["Grants"]:
            if (
                "URI" in grant["Grantee"]
                and grant["Grantee"]["URI"].endswith("AllUsers")
                and grant["Permission"] in ["READ", "FULL_CONTROL"]
            ):
                return True
        return False
    except Exception:
        # Cannot determine if s3 object is public.
        return False
```